# SPOTFIRE Custom Expression How to get Conditional Sum of a Column Value

Tags: spotfire

I have a data table as below

| Region | KPIName | KPI Value | Station | YearMth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Total Units | 5000 | A1 | 202301 |
| A | Total Hours | 500 | A1 | 202301 |
| A | Total Units/Hour |  | A1 | 202301 |
| A | KPI X | 5412 | A1 | 202301 |
| A | KPI Y | 2252 | A1 | 202301 |

This table contains multiple regions,stations,yearMth.
The output i m expecting in a cross tab like below

[image]
|

```
 
  The Total Units should sum(KPI Value) By Station, YearMth   (station is unique across regions)
  The Total Hours should sum(KPI value) By Station, YearMth   
  The Total Units/Hour should be sum(Total Units)/sum(Total Hours)  
  when i tried a custom expression like 
   Sum(case [kpi_value] 
    when 'Total Units/Hour' then (sum(case [kpi_value] when 'Total Units' then [KPI Value] else 0 end) over (Intersect([Station],[YearMth])))
    else [KPI Value] END) /
Max(Sum(case [kpi_value]
    when 'Total Units/Hour' then (sum(case [kpi_value] when 'Total Hours' then [KPI Value] else 0 end) over (Intersect([station],[YearMth])))
    else 0 END),1) AS [Value]

   but i am not getting the result correctly..
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The Total Units should ..". Is the Total Units going to be a new calculated column? Can you provide a mock up of the desired result?

Comment: rephrased my scenario to make it clear.. Thanks